# Angular Material: md-datepicker CSS display issue

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I've upgraded to Angular Material 0.11.1. I'm using Angular JS v1.4.6. I'm trying to implement the new date-picker function. The issue I have is when I use the standard code as follows:

```
<md-content>
<h4>Standard date-picker</h4>
<md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
</md-content>
```

When I select the picker, I get a wierd display issue where half the screen is grey and can see part of the datepicker box. Once this is executed and try to select anything else with pop-up box the same thing happens. Anyone knows why this happening and how to fix it?

Images below:

[image: Before Photo]
[image: After Date selected]

Comment: Hey @Ka tech Did you ever work out what was happening here? I am having the same issue today but with a white block at the bottom of the page

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I myself was having the exact same issue, every time I clicked to open the `md-datepicker`, I had a large white block at the bottom of my page.

After spending some time monitoring the page behaviour on clicking the `md-datepicker`, I realised that on clicking the `md-datepicker`, `angular material` was dynamically changing the css styling of the `<html>` and `<body>` classes in my css stylesheets, like so:

```
<body class="" style="position: fixed; width: 100%; top: -231px;">

<html lang="en" style="overflow-y: scroll;">
```

as a quick fix, I have set my body class like so, to override the dynamic changes:

```
body {
top: 0px !important;
}
```

Hopefully this will help others with the same issue.

Comment: You are the man, this worked for me! People suggested v1.1.1 fixes it but thats not true!

Comment: Glad it could be of some use! @Abdel

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and applied the following tag in `md-datepicker`, it worked all fine for me :)

```
style="position:fixed;"
```